# Using PAM in a C program to update user password

Tags: c, linux, passwords, pam

I'm creating a C program that updates a user's password. To do this I'm using PAM. I based my minimal code off of [off of this.](http://linux-pam.org/Linux-PAM-html/adg-example.html)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <security/pam_appl.h>
#include <security/pam_misc.h>
#include <security/pam_modules.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    setuid(0);
    int retval;
    int started;

    const char *user = "user";
    pam_handle_t *pamh=NULL;
    const struct pam_conv conv = {
    misc_conv,
    NULL
    };

    if(argc == 2)
    {
        const char *updated = argv[1];

        started = pam_start("update_password", user, &conv, &pamh);
        int setTok;
        if(started == PAM_SUCCESS)
        {
            setTok = pam_set_item(pamh, PAM_AUTHTOK_TYPE, updated);
            int setPass;
            setPass = pam_chauthtok(pamh, PAM_SILENT);
            retval = setPass;
        }
        printf("Started: %d\n", started);
        printf("SetTok: %d\n", setTok);
        printf("SetPass: %d\n", retval); 

    }
    else{
        printf("incorrect number of args");
    }

    if (pam_end(pamh,retval) != PAM_SUCCESS){
        pamh = NULL;
        exit(1);
    }

    return ( retval == PAM_SUCCESS ? 1:0);
}
```

The output is this:

```
Started: 0
SetTok: 0
SetPass: 20
```

I've used this to determine what the numbers are: [PAM Status Codes](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/8329799/chap5.htm)

Primarily, I don't understand how to pass my updated password to `pam_chauthtok()`. I used `pam_set_item` which "succeeded" but didn't actually help me in getting information to the `pam_chauthtok` function. I think I might need to somehow pass the updated password to `pam_handle_t` or `pam_conv`, but I'm not sure how to even do that, nor have I figured out how that would ultimately send the info to `pam_chauthtok()`

I promise, I have googled plenty and I'm trying my best, I'm just very lost now. Please ask for clarification if what I said or wrote makes little sense. I'm actually new to C, so if there are any blatant syntax errors I'm missing, that's why.

Comment: Have a look at the following source code: http://www.openldap.org/lists/openldap-software/200211/msg00255.html

Answer (score -1):

you must see libmisc/pam_pass_non_interactive.c in shadow-masters github. This is what chpasswd uses. There is an interesting usage of pam_conv by registering a callback inside it. The new password is just put into a bucket of the input parameter response in the callback arguments and it gets updated to pam. Ideally invoking chpasswd like below in linux shell goes via this flow and hits the password stack in the service file.

echo : | chpasswd

OR if you are not logged in as root and given sudoer perm to chpasswd

echo : | sudo chpasswd